# Azure DevOps REST API - Get Capacity Bar from each Member

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to get the workload foreach teammember from the Devops API, so that I can visualize the same like what you can see in the picture and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/adjust-work?view=azure-devops

I already saw that there is a capacity endpoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/capacities/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1.
But this shows only the available hours foreach member in a week. I want all workItems per Member (hours summed up).
Is there a possible way to achieve this? Am I missing something?

[image: Wanted]

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid that there is not a REST API can get the value directly at present. Before the value is displayed on the page, it is computed several times at the backend. After your assigned the work items to members, the page will show as following. It will show all work items per members(hours summed up) and capacity hours.
[image]

If you want to get the value by REST API, you can check the API from Fiddler, then follow the format of the API to pass the your value. Or you can get the member capacity and the Iteration work days then use the script to calculate this value manually.

Comment: You can use POST method to query the work items per member with WIQL. You can refer to here.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#examples

Comment: So this means that I get a list of work Items, but I still have to call every single one to get the remaining work on each task?